# Magento ER diagram of 2.x

Tags: magento2

I wonder to know if you have an ER diagram of Magento 2 (as the same you published of magento 1.0.x (http://anna.voelkl.at/uploads/magento/ce1922.png)

Answer (score 1):

@Fede Moreno You can create your own using https://www.dbvis.com/ or https://www.navicat.com/ (for your respective db). There isn't anything that's been published for M2 yet that I've seen.

I just fired up DB Visualizer, entered my connection string info, double clicked "TABLE" underneath the available tables for my db, and then clicked on the "References" tab, and then the ERD was generated for me to work with.

I hope this helps you.